# Missing packages during manual package install

Tags: apt, dpkg

Sometimes I download a deb, say for Google Chrome, or the Github atom.io editor.

I then run `sudo dpkg -i <package>.deb`

I then get the error:
`Errors were encountered while processing: ...`

Which looks like it is missing dependancies.

How do I fix missing dependancies from a manual package install?

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this problem with:
`sudo apt-get install -f`